# Code Coverage analysis for .NET Compact Framework 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, code-coverage, smart-device

Is there any Recommended solution for deriving Code Coverage analysis for .NET CF (Compact Framework), SmartDevice (Pocket PC) applications.

We are using vsinstr +vsperfmon for Desktop Applications.

I could find only following:

1. DotCover: That will work when running application in Debug from
   Visual Studio.
2. NCover, as long as the application is run as
   a stand-alone application, and not within an emulator or on a mobile
   device.

Both approaches are not working for us. To be precise, we want Coverage to be analyzed to evaluate the completion of the TestCases from QA. That can be done when QA will run Test Cases upon the build, which is instrumented for Code Coverage analysis.

Any help is appreciable!!!

Regards
Sumeet

Comment: Have you tried creating a desktop project with your sources and have the coverage tool analyze that one instead?

Comment: @leppie OpenCover will have the same restriction as NCover, as they both use the COM profile interface. It's been a long time since I did CF stuff but as I recall the emulator, or even the device does not have a full runtime that exposes the profile interface. I took the approach suggested by ctacke and recompiled my stuff for the desktop and then ran my tests, however I suspect you are trying to run coverage against the full application. You may be able to compike the whole thing for the desktop but you may need to add some conditional compilation around any CF stuff

Comment: The challenge is, we are having some Automation scripts prepared and ready to run for Pocket PC devices under the Test Environment. While running these scripts, we want to make sure that how much functional/code areas the Automation Testing is covering and what are left to do. This can be done only when we are able to run those Automation Scripts on the instruments or monitored build over the Devices. That's the way we use for Desktop Builds.